# How to know changes in polygons?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, editing

I'm writing a PyQGIS script. I succeed in accessing GIS vector data (lists) from my remote server (thanks to urllib). I succeed in displaying geometries and attributes.

Now, I would like manage layer's editions and modifications. I must find a way to know the polygons that were been modified, deleted or added. Could you throw light for me?

Secondly, I would like to send these edits and these modifications toward the remote server. Could you tell me how to do that please?

In order to be more explicit I paste the useful github link:

https://github.com/picardie-nature/clicnat-qgis/blob/master/plugin.py

Comment: It would be great to have some background about what you are doing. Are you trying to fetch and edit data from a database? There would be better ways than writing your own plugin.

Comment: Hello, thanks. Of course. I paste the usefull github link: https://github.com/picardie-nature/clicnat-qgis/blob/master/plugin.py